# ListView OnItemClick not firing in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager that contain 2 fragments and in the fragment, there is 2 different listview which I have attached a OnItemClickListener to the ListView. But the code is not firing even though I click on the listview. I believe this to be due to the fact that the ViewPager override OnTouch event for the listview. How do I disable the ontouch event or to prevent the event from overriding my listview event.

This is the MainActivity code

```
ViewPager viewPager = v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SearchViewPageAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    TabLayout tabLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.SearchTabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(R.string.first_title);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(R.string.second_title);
```

My listview is inside viewpager which create 2 fragment.

```
listView = v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter(context);
    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: I'm not so sure that the `ViewPager` is to blame. But anyway, you could start by overriding [onTouchEvent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)) for the `ViewPager`. (You create a custom `ViewPager` class which inherits everything from the original `ViewPager` but has its own implementation of `onTouchEvent()`) Then you use debugging to check whether the method is called when you click the `ListView` and how the standard implementation handles the touch event.

Comment: Yep, the method is called when I tapped on the listview. The listview only fire listener only works when I scrolled vertically upwards. Horizontally still control the ViewPager

Comment: Then maybe you can store the time for each DOWN in `onTouchEvent()` and if the next UP happens shortly after the DOWN (for example 200ms) then you decide it's a click event and so the `ViewPager` should not handle it. I'm not 100% sure but I think it's enough to return "false" in these cases from the `ViewPager`'s `onTouchEvent()` and let the runtime find the next interested `View` (which should be the `ListView`)